# Signing Identity and Provisioning Profile confusion Gluon Mobile

Tags: ios, javafx, pom.xml, gluon-mobile

https://foojay.io/today/creating-mobile-apps-with-javafx-part-3/

In the above article, what is she referring to by `<providedSigningIdentity>` and `<providedProvisioningProfile>`? Do I upload by certificate files, or maybe my App ID? I am looking at my developer portal, and I can't find anything like an identifier related to the Signing Identity and Provisioning Profile, just my certificates.

Comment: Check the official docs for iOS distribution: https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_ios, and the final section [Build your application](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_ios_distribution_build121).

Comment: @JoséPereda so in the Provisioning Profile section, I just put the name of my Provisioning Profile, and for Signing Identity, I put my app ID prefix? I have followed these steps thus far by the way.

Comment: Signing identity is not related to your app. It is related to your Apple ID. If you run `gluonfx:link` again with verbose true you can see the logs with the provisioning profile and signing identity that the plugin is finding to sign your app (or you can check the client-debug.log files).